# Replacing single '\' with '\\' in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, patternsyntaxexception

How do I replace a single `'\'` with `'\\'`?  When I run `replaceAll()` then I get this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
                           Unexpected internal error near index 1 \
                                                                  ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1466)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2190)
    at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:13)
Java Result: 1
```

My code:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\HUSAIN\\My Documents\\My Palettes";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to replace         `str = str.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\")` by `   `str = str.replaceAll("^\\$", "^\\\\$"); `

Comment: What do you mean, replace single '\' with '\'? Sounds like a noop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`String.replaceAll(String,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  is regex.
[`String.replace(String,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)  will do what you want.

The following...

```
String str = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\HUSAIN\\My Documents\\My Palettes";
System.out.println(str);
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
System.out.println(str);
```

Produces...

> C:\Documents and Settings\HUSAIN\My Documents\My Palettes
>   C:\\Documents and Settings\\HUSAIN\\My Documents\\My Palettes

Answer (score 14):

`\` is also a special character in regexp. This is why you should do something like this:

```
    str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to first scape the `\` for the string and then scape it for the regex, it would be `\\\\` for each slash.

Answer (score 2):

In a String literal, `\` must be escaped with another `\`. And in a reges, a `\` must also be escaped by another `\\`. So, you must escape every `\` four times: `\\\\`.

Another way is to use `Pattern.quote("\\")` (for the regex) and `Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\")` for the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Pattern.quote` to make it easier for you to escape the value, such as:

```
str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
```

or, you can just use `String.replace`:

```
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

See: [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29), [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [Matcher.quoteReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
filePath = filePath.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
```

This one worked perfectly.

```
OUTPUT:
filePath = C:\abc\
```