# Selenium web driver not able to login in to internal website due to '/' in username (windows domain)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried

```
public void Login_PopUP()
    {   
    driver.get(url);
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userID")).sendKeys("domain/username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  }
```

This is not working. I am not able to enter the input in the login alert pop up also username has a special character '\', how to handle it.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: At what point your script fails? What error are you getting?

Comment: Store username as variable and pass it to send keys instead of directly writing in the username in sendkeys

Comment: @Pooja I dont think there is any way to write in pop-up window by selenium , it only provides method to accept and reject the pop up boxes. Even if you want to write something there then please have a look here to get more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

just pass the application URL with username & password as,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://username:password@the-site.com");
```