# handle windows login pop-up using selenium web driver for https website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario:
I am opening a https website, I get a login pop-up that is not identified by selenium webdriver. I have searched and found the below link which had similar question.

[How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)

I tried he solution given by @Pavel Janicek to pass the credentials via URL
It does not working for me, I mean after the browser is opened it keeps processing nothing happens after that.

In my case, it is a https site,i need to give username@domainname & password to login, giving only username will not work

my url looks like this
https://username@domainname:password@sitename.com

Has anyone faced this kind of problem?

Thanks

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, It remains in the "connecting.." state

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT auth with this window(in selenium without any additional framework as Robot). But you can auth without getting this window. Try change URL to: http://user:password@www.yourserveradress.com

if this will not help, you need to create separated profile in browser, pass authentication on this server and remember password and use this profile in selenium. Also I think its possible to use Windows active directory authentication, but cannot sure about details.