# Entering Username/Password in Authentication pop-up window

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, awtrobot

When I launch a website from Eclipse (selenium) it pops up a authentication box as below:

[image]

Here I am unable to enter Username and password, here are the things I tried:
1) Switching of Handle to pop up and identifying Xpath 
2) Sending Username and Password in the URL ([How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)) 
3) Sikuli (but requires image capture when executed in different system) 
4) Using Robot function

```
        Robot rb = new Robot();
        StringSelection username = new StringSelection("XXXXX");
        System.out.println("Entering username");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        //tab to password entry field
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Enter password by ctrl-v
        StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("YYYYYYY");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        //press enter
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

None of the above worked till now, just after reaching the website (driver.get(URL)) the control does not seem to come back to eclipse

Comment: Update: Tried with AutoIT as well, not working

Comment: Did you test the autoIT script first?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha: Yes, I called the script after/before launching the url  with some wait time, however the script does not run, i added a print statement in eclipse between launch url and call AutoIt script, this never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoIT scripts to fill that windows. That is the only way to elegantly handle this issue in Windows with Selenium. Check *Handle Windows based Authentication Pop Up in Selenium using AutoIt* at http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Will someone care to answer the reason for downvoting this answer? I am using it for years and know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work, it can be refactored :)

```
driver.navigate().to("url");
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("username");
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(2000);
selection = new StringSelection("password");
clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```