# How to avoid username & password alert prompt (while authenticating proxy) in Selenium webdriver, chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to avoid username & password alert prompt (while authenticating proxy) in Selenium webdriver, chrome?

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Selenium/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 
        proxy.setHttpProxy("xx.xx.xxx.xx:yyyy"); 
        proxy.setSslProxy("xx.xx.xxx.xx:yyy"); 
        proxy.setSocksUsername("abcd");
        proxy.setSocksPassword("efgh");
        capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("https://abcd:efgh@whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

Comment: Are you want to disable it or want to pass somevalues

Comment: I want to pass username and password.. the proxy server is authentication enabled!

Comment: Pass User name and password in place of USername and password and then write URL driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");

Comment: did'nt work.. prompt still coming!...
using chromedriver 2.32
chrome version : 61.0.3163.100 
Selenium webdriver : 3.4.0
FYI

Comment: Please paste ur code in question

Comment: I have edited my question..that is the complete code i'm using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://abcd:efgh@whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

Comment: Dear you have to set my Chrome driver path set yours

Comment: yes. i set mine only!..  ( previously i edited and copied ur location.. but in my code was different.. now I copied whatever my code is)

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: Popup window appearing to enter username & ppassword.. it should not appear!

Comment: It is running well in my site