# Selenium Webdriver java automate window

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Could you please tell me how to automate this window using webdriver and java - https://www.screencast.com/t/Zf19fumzl1j

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not automate the window ( for HTTP Authentication ) using selenium. You can use robot framework to automate this window.
Here is the approach :

1. Instead of putting your url like http://yoururl.com, put it like http://username:password@yoururl.com. It will bring a confirmation dialog.

   driver.get("http://username:password@yoururl.com");
2. To click the confirmation dialog use following code

   ```
   import java.awt.AWTException;
   import java.awt.Robot;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

   public void clikOKOfConfirmationDialog(){
   try {
       Robot robot = new Robot();
       robot.delay(2000);
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   } catch (AWTException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   ```

This approach might not be work with IE.
Hope this will help.