# python selenium firefox, special character @ for authentication popup

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to log in with python Selenium to a webpage that wants authentication credentials.
Unlike the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)
my username is an email address, so it contains the '@' character (and I'm using Python).

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
webpage = 'http://somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news'
username = 'myname@mymailbox.com'
password = 'mypassword'
url = username + ':' + password + '@' + webpage
print(url)
driver.get(url)
```

output is

```
myname@mymailbox.com:mypassword@http://somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "question.py", line 12, in <module>
  driver.get(url)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 324, in get
  self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Malformed URL: myname@mymailbox.com:mypassword@http://somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news is not a valid URL.
```

I believe the problem is from the extra '@' character.  How do I put it in without creating a malformed URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have a right url, it need to be `http://username:password@url`, but you have `username:password@http://url`

try this

```
webpage = 'somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news'
username = 'myname@mymailbox.com'
password = 'mypassword'

url = 'http://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, webpage)
```

**Output**

```
http://myname@mymailbox.com:mypassword@somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news
```

but i think this will cause the problems, because you have two `@` better way would be to use `send_keys`, for example

```
webpage = 'http://somewhere.com/cgi-bin/dirwrap.cgi?template=template&path=news'

driver.get(url)

email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('email input xpath')
email_inpit.clear()
email_input.send_keys(username)

pwd_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('password input xpath')
pwd_inpit.clear()
pwd_input.send_keys(password)

# and after this you need to click on `ok` btn
```