# Selenium FileUpload accept() is not clicking button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

Having opened the file chooser dialog in IE,

```
self.webDiver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

Tried the above line but does not click the open button.

> IE Version 11.2580.14393.0;
>
> Windows Server 2016 Standard

The dialog that gets displayed is "Choose File to Upload", this dialog has a File name text box with a Combobox + Open button as well as an Open button that is a SplitButtonControl with options to Open/Open readonly or save as previous version.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Fixed question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge and chrome version 83 alerts for a OAuth or Single Sign on User Credentials are a special case of Alert.

Dialog window is not part of the Browser, its a Operating system dialog (some technicalities are glossed over here) and launches in a separate process.

I was unable to find a Selenium method for interacting with Windows Dialog so used [python uiautomation for windows](http://%20https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows/) instead:

```
window2 = uiautomation.WindowControl(searchDepth=1, ClassName='Credential Dialog Xaml Host')
window2.SetActive()
window2.SendKeys('username{TAB}password')
window2.ButtonControl(searchDepth=10, Name='OK').Click()
```