# Selenium "click" command does not complete until authentication is finished

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a simple Java code that uses Selenium ChromeDriver.

The flow is simple: The driver goes to a website --> find a HTML element and click it --> An authentication pop-up appears --> ...

But here the problem arises. The program could not continue after the click command, which is: "`href.click()`".

I MANUALLY entered the username and password to the authentication pop-up, and the print command only works AFTER that.

Even if I do not provides the authentication, the print command should still be activated after the click command has finished. But, in this case, it doesn't.

Which means, the click command "`href.click()`" only finishes when the authentication pop-up is already finished. But since the click is an atomic command, how and when am I supposed to enter the authentication details ?

I tried using an alert, or added any lines of codes AFTER the click line but none of them worked. 
I also tried adding "`driver.get("http://username:password@somesite.com/")`", but it doesn't work also.

```java
    public void site_header_is_on_home_page() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://somesite.com/");

        WebElement href = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://xyz.../']"));

        href.click();
        //Nothing works after this line.//

        System.out.println("cccc");

    }
```

[The screen after the "driver.get("http://somesite.com/")" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvBpG.png)

[The screen after the click command. An authentication pop-up is issued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0rT9.png)

Comment: Try this `driver.get("https://UserName:Password@Example.com")`

Comment: I tried , but it did not work

Comment: Read this .. may be its help you.. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1917&q=authentication&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I searched that, but it did not work for my case. This one this different I think

Comment: @DukeTrịnh Have you tried surrounding the href.click() with a try/catch block?

Comment: @MateMrše I just try after u suggest. But no exceptions seem to raises.

Comment: you can login using AutoIT also check this video https://youtu.be/XYuyIMeW6g4 may be it helps you..