# Why the Selenium script project can not continue after click()

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This is my code:

**myproject.py**

```py
userName.send_keys(user_name)
passWord.send_keys(pass_word)

Button.click()

print("1")
```

When I do `Button.click()`, the pages can successfully JUMP but it CANNOT continue to the NEXT STEP,  even it is just a `print()` statement.

The next page is displayed like the image below.

[image]
[image]

In the next page, it has alert windows up there, and I cannot switch to it. The program gave me an error message:

> [20120:10844:0529/150013.017:ERROR:textfield.cc(1773)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

And I have used `submit()` too, it also did not change. I am really confused about this issue so I checked the lib of selenium:

**webelement.py from Selenium**

```py
def click(self):
    """Clicks the element."""
    print("1")
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
    print("2")
```

Somehow the `print("2")` cannot be printed.

If someone knows the reason for this, I will appreciate it if you can tell me.

Comment: It is blocking at the alert (I have tried to switch to it without any luck), could you check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Suggestion in the link is to bypass the login page/ authentication pop-up. Use ```driver.get("https://username:password@yourUrl")```. yourUrl is not your login page but the next one, which is the one halting the click.

Comment: It not work, because the link is not changed whether login or not,

Comment: Got it, this is I know issue from chromedriver: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1917&q=authentication&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary.
Can you run with FireFox? I am able to switch to the authentication pop-up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never thought it will be a bug