# How to handle the website pop up using Java in Selenium Web driver in Mozilla?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to enter the user id and password for the pop up appears as part of my website authentication and proceed further . I have referred few threads which is 5 years old and not working

[How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)

Any one have solution recently for this . I need to enter user name and password and click ok and proceed further

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bazh3.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: If you are using a selenium-java version before 3.8.0, you can use: `Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
  a.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("username", "password"));`

Comment: Previously i used this driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  For that i got error as Symbol cannot be identified for the Symbol Keys now for this Syntax too UserandPassword same error comes should i need to recheck something