# Handling Chromelogin Popup window using OATS

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAvm0.png)How to handle Chrome login popup.. I have a Situation where:
-> there is a button, and when it is clicked, it creates an authentication popup; now I can not append username and password to it as URL is dynamic.
-> Also I have to verify whether the pop up is displayed, then have to enter credentials and submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Also, show your attempt of solving the issue.

Comment: @Jonah-- my problem is, after clicking on Configure button, url is not getting loaded. and also under url--"about blank" is getting displayed.. not sure.. why this is happening, if I navigate manually its working as per expected.

Comment: @Jonah here's my attempt.

Comment: @Jonah -- any input on this?

Comment: Have you read the answers under the URL I have provided? Especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719740/8102135) one.

Comment: @Jonah -- Hi Jonah, I tried above but nothing is working over here..