# How to handle a popup window that does not exist in the WebDriver with Selenium/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, alert

I have a popup window which does not exist in the WebDriver.
[image]

There is no WindowHandle for it, so I cannot address it as Alert.
[image]

But since the cursor is in the right position, is there any way to just send username TAB password ENTER as Keys?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the approach where you send username and password in URL Request:

```java
http://username:password@the-site.com
```

The username is `username` and password is `password` and the rest is the URL of that web page

```java
String URL = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + theWebPageUrl;
driver.get(URL);
```

The more detailed answer is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522757/3485434)

Comment: I had tried this and it unfortunately does not work. The popup is there anyway and I am not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

in case you working with Selenium 4, have a look at this, might be worth trying - https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-login-popup-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java/

especially this section

> Handling login pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Selenium 4 beta
> version

Comment: the alert is not found

Comment: check out my updated comment above

Answer (score 0):

try to access popup as an app element (browser) with [RPA.Desktop.Desktop](https://rpaframework.org/libraries/desktop/python.html#) api or [RPA.Desktop.Windows](https://rpaframework.org/libraries/desktop_windows/python.html) api. For Python it's `pip install rpaframework`