# How to authenticate using Windows Authentication in Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I need to automate a test that uses Windows Authentication.

I know that the the prompt that opens up is not part of the HTML page, yet why my code is not working:

```
login_page.click_iwa()
sleep(5)
self.page.keyboard.type('UserName')
sleep(5)
self.page.keyboard.press('Tab')
self.page.keyboard.type('Password')
```

Comment: Hey, not able to understand iwa. can you check if iwa is a frame? usually, authorizations are iframe for which you might need frameLocator (https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator) then only frame.keyboard functions will work

Comment: @tushi43 IWA is a windows prompt that asks for a username and password for a web site. It is not a dialog or normal alert.

Comment: Have you tried this URL method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522757/8835695

Comment: No, Windows authentication isn't a prompt. That's the entire point. There's absolutely no need for a prompt. The browser connects to the server using the user's account transparently. Credentials are only asked *by the browser*, when the current user isn't recognized. The prompt isn't displayed in a web page so isn't visible to Playwright

Comment: The easy solution is to run the tests using an account that's allowed to connect to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a virtual keyboard:

```
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey


def press_key(key):
    press(key)


def type_text(text):
    typewrite(text)


def special_keys(special, normal):
    hotkey(special, normal)
```

Then, after I implemented the virtual keyboard, I did this:

```
def login_iwa(self, user_name='User321', password='123456', need_to_fail=False):
        pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
        self.click_iwa()
        sleep(7)
        type_text(user_name)
        sleep(1)
        press_key('Tab')
        sleep(1)
        type_text(password)
        sleep(1)
        press_key('Enter')
        sleep(2)
        if need_to_fail:
            press_key('Tab')
            sleep(1)
            press_key('Tab')
            sleep(1)
            press_key('Tab')
            sleep(1)
            press_key('Enter')
            sleep(1)
```

I used pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False because sometime the popup was hiding behind the screen or was openning up on the 2nd screen.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using more protocol-based approaches. I have tested the following methods to authenticate using the [the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth) endpoint with the username and password set to `admin`, and all of them worked successfully. Below, you'll find the complete code for each method to make it easy to test them by simply copy-pasting:

1. Passing the credentials in the URL:

   ```
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(url="http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
        context.close()
        browser.close()
   ```
2. Passing the credentials to the `http_credentials` context parameter:

   ```
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context(
            http_credentials={
                "username": "admin",
                "password": "admin"
            }
        )
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(url="http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
        context.close()
        browser.close()
   ```
3. Using the `Authorization` HTTP header (however, there are other [authentication types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes)):

   ```
    import base64
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    def generate_basic_authentication_header_value(username: str, password: str) -> str:
        token = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(username, password).encode("utf-8")).decode("ascii")
        return "Basic {}".format(token)

    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context(
            extra_http_headers={
                "Authorization": generate_basic_authentication_header_value("admin", "admin"),
            }
        )
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(url="http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
        context.close()
        browser.close()
   ```

Comment: This only works for basic authentication, not Windows authentication

Comment: @Alireza Your answer ignore the use of the playwright tool. I don't want a work around via the URL.